# Compiling Flutter Engine on Windows

Tags: flutter, build

I'm trying to build the Flutter engine on Windows. I think VS 2017 is needed and I only have that version of VS installed. I had to do these two things that were not among the instructions [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine#compiling-for-windows):

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2017
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
```

Then, in the compile insturctions [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine#compiling-for-windows), I'm getting errors after `python .\flutter\tools\gn --unoptimized`.

> λ python .\flutter\tools\gn --unoptimized Generating GN files in:
>   out\host_debug_unopt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 154, in 
>       main()   File "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 121, in main
>       args = _SetupScript(cpu, win_sdk_path)   File "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 68, in _SetupScript
>       return [os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.environ['GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH'],
>   File
>   "C:\Installs\Flutter\building\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_15_chromium14_bin\python\bin\lib\os.py",
>   line 425, in **getitem**
>       return self.data[key.upper()] KeyError: 'GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH' ERROR at //build/toolchain/win/BUILD.gn:28:18: Script returned
>   non-zero exit code. toolchain_data = exec_script("setup_toolchain.py",
>                    ^---------- Current dir: C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/ Command:
>   C:/Installs/Flutter/building/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_15_chromium14_bin/python/bin/python.exe
>   C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community"
>   ../../third_party/gyp/pylib/gyp/win_tool.py "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10"
>   "C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;Arm64Unused" x64 Returned 1.
>   See //BUILD.gn:6:1: which caused the file to be included.
>   group("default") { ^------------------

After doing `set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017` now I get:

> λ python .\flutter\tools\gn --unoptimized Generating GN files in:
>   out\host_debug_unopt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 154, in 
>       main()   File "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 126, in main
>       env = _ExtractImportantEnvironment(variables)   File "C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py",
>   line 50, in _ExtractImportantEnvironment
>       'required to be set to valid path' % required) Exception: Environment variable "SYSTEMROOT" required to be set to valid path
>   ERROR at //build/toolchain/win/BUILD.gn:28:18: Script returned
>   non-zero exit code. toolchain_data = exec_script("setup_toolchain.py",
>                    ^---------- Current dir: C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/ Command:
>   C:/Installs/Flutter/building/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_15_chromium14_bin/python/bin/python.exe
>   C:/Installs/Flutter/engine/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017"
>   ../../third_party/gyp/pylib/gyp/win_tool.py "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10"
>   "C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;Arm64Unused" x64 Returned 1.
>   See //BUILD.gn:6:1: which caused the file to be included.
>   group("default") { ^------------------

`SYSTEMROOT` is already set:

```
λ echo %SYSTEMROOT%
C:\WINDOWS
```

I tried these, but still I'm getting the same error.

```
set WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1
SET use_sysroot=0
SET USE_SYSROOT=0
```

How can I get over this issue and compile the Flutter engine?

Edit: by the way, I hit enter when it asks for a username `Username for 'https://chrome-internal.googlesource.com':`, could it be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it was supposed to be `set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community`. Missed out the `Community` part. Figured it out after digging in the python files a bit.

So, these below should be added to the instructions:

1. Set these variables

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2017
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community
```

2. Install [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) with Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86/amd64 Apps.